# Float breaks for fluid design

Tags: html, css

EDIT : I have checked and i think its the image on right side which is creating the problem as if i remove the image everything is fine, is there anyways to make sure the image resizes with design, i have used max-width:100% for image but after certain point i guess its not resizing.

EDIT:  Please resize the result page to understand the problem, the left area instead of floating goes to bottom, even though its a fluid size design

Due to the image of right side the float breaks when resized, i have added max width 100% still breaks off. Is there a solution to it so that is resizes yest does'nt break of?

```
 <header>
                <div id="branding"> <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" width="542" height="120" alt=""/></a> 
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>
                </div>
        </header>


                <section>
                <div id="content">
                <h2>Wir arbeiten an der Erstellung 
        unserer <strong>Internetpräsenz</strong></h2></div>
                </section>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

@media \0screen {
  img { 
    width: auto; /* for ie 8 */
  }
}

header {
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    float: right;
    display: table;
}


section {
    width: 65%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #e51b24;
    float: left;
    display: table;
}

/* Logo and Address Styling */

#branding {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding:10%;
}

#branding p {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: #717171;
    font-size: 23px;
    line-height:1.5em;
}
#branding a {
    color: #717171;
    text-decoration: underline;
}


/* Main Content Styling */

#content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color:white;
    padding:8%;
}

#content h2{
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:70px;
    line-height:1.3em;
}
```

JS fiddle Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Uv9Wp/embedded/result/

http://jsfiddle.net/Uv9Wp/

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish. What do you mean break off? Is the desired result what is displayed in the first link?

Comment: i am happy with result, but when you resize the page you'll see the design does'nt hold the left side goes to bottom. please resize to check.

Comment: can you consider changing the order of elements in HTML markup?

Comment: Oh I see. In order to keep them (the header and section) beside each other unfailingly you should change your display to: `display:inline;`

Comment: i have changed order, this time it does'nt looks like tis breaking but the images and text on right side goes to bottom and a scrollbar appears. i think i do have to use media query for this no other option i guess

Comment: @Fourth display:inline conflicts with display:table-cell as i want to keep the text aligned perfectly in middle. is there any alternative? there must be something..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Uv9Wp/15/)**

I changed the order of the HTML markup to be able to aply the `table-cell` property on `section` and `header` (and removed padding on their children).

HTML :

```
<section>
    <div id="content">
         <h2>Wir arbeiten an der Erstellung 
    unserer <strong>Internetpräsenz</strong></h2>
    </div>
</section>

<header>
    <div id="branding"> <a href="#"><img src="http://froggyadventures.com/wp-content/uploads/galleries/post-93/full/placeholder%20-%20Copy%20%282%29.gif" width="542" height="120" alt=""/></a> 
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS :

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
body{display:table;}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
@media \0screen {
    img {
        width: auto;
        /* for ie 8 */
    }
}
header {
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
section {
    width: 65%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #e51b24;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
/* Logo and Address Styling */
 #branding {    
    text-align: center;
    padding:10%;
    width: 80%;
}
#branding p {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: #717171;
    font-size: 23px;
    line-height:1.5em;
}
#branding a {
    color: #717171;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
/* Main Content Styling */
 #content {
    width: 84%;
    padding:8%;
    text-align:left;
    color:white;
}
#content h2 {
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:60px;
    line-height:1.3em;
}
```

Comment: but i need the padding so how do i add pading without breaking of design?

Answer (score 0):

Remove display table from header and from section. That should get them to stay beside each other.

Comment: that will work but then there will be another problem, the texts and content will not be aligned vertically in middle.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the reason why it's happening is because the text in the red container runs out of space. The word "Internetpräsenz" can't break onto a new line so instead the entire container drops down.

I would suggest to create a few break points using media queries and shrink down the font-size for smaller resolutions.

Here's a great read on media queries and how to use them: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

And here's an example of it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/Uv9Wp/5/

```
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
    #content{padding:4%}
    #content h2{font-size:14px;}
}
```

Comment: in the result i have checked, it only makes text smaller but still it breaks down, i think its the image size problem as as soon as i delete the image everything works fine. is there any way i can replace the image for various sizes or make the image responsive.

Comment: The problem is with the text. It breaks when one word can no longer fit on a single line. As you can see in my example it now breaks then the word "scrambled" can no longer fit in the container.

If you don't want to add break points there's one other thing you can do. Set a min-width on the body right when ti breaks, to prevent it from getting any smaller. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Uv9Wp/16/